# Как при записи в файл пропускать дубль строки?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте подскажите как при записи в файл чтоб не записывать дубли строки
делаю вот так

```
if (!isset($_POST['action']))
{
//форма
}
else
{
$error = "";
    if ( isset($_POST["nome"]) && !empty($_POST["nome"])) $nome = $_POST["nome"]; else $error .= "<li>Не введено название</li>";


    $nome = stripslashes($_POST['nome']);

    if ( !empty($error) ) echo("<ul style='color:red;'>".$error."</ul>");
    else // записываем в файл
    {
        if (is_writeable("../data/bot.dat"))
        {

            $f = fopen("../data/bot.dat","a+");
            $write_text = "$nome \n";
            fputs($f,$write_text);
            fclose($f);
            echo("Файл добавлен.");
       }
       else echo("Не удалось записать в файл"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: ну вот совершенно непонятно, что вам подсказать. что вы туда пишете, как пишете. Встроенного параметра, запрещающего писать дубли, нет

Comment: читайте его при помощи file(), получится массив. записывайте, если строки нет  в массиве

Comment: я шото намудрил но незнаю как дубли пропускать

Comment: ну самое простое - in_array()

Comment: а как это применить

Comment: Вам стоит прочитать книгу по php. И сразу всё станет понятным. Или хотя бы прочитать документацию по функции in_array()

Comment: читаю ну вы если хотите подсказать подскажите или

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов - прочитать файл в массив, произвести поиск по массиву, и в случае отсутствия искомой строки, добавить её в массив, и перезаписать текстовый файл. Пример:

```
if (!isset($_POST['action'])) {
    echo '<form method="post">'.
        '<input type="text" name="nome" />'.
        '<input type="submit" name="action" />'.
        '</form>';
} elseif (!empty($_POST['nome'])) {
    $file = '../data/bot.dat';
    $array = file_exists($file) 
        ? file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) : [];

    $nome = trim($_POST['nome']);

    if (in_array($nome, $array)) {
        echo '<ul style="color:red;"><li>Такая запись уже существует!</li></ul>';
    } else {
        $array[] = $nome;

        if (file_put_contents($file, join(PHP_EOL, $array))) {
            echo '<ul style="color:green;"><li>Запись добавлена!</li></ul>';
        } else {
            echo '<ul style="color:red;"><li>Не удалось записать в файл!</li></ul>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<ul style="color:red;"><li>Не введено название!</li></ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так решил

```
    // читаем файл в массив строк без добавления символа перевода строки в конец каждой строки
$list = file("../data/bot.dat", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$bot_list = array_map('trim', $list);
if (is_writeable("../data/bot.dat")){
  $f = fopen("../data/bot.dat","a+");
  $write_text = "$nome_bot \n"; 
// если строка отсутствует в массиве строк файла, то добавляем ее в файл
if (in_array($nome_bot, $bot_list)) {
    echo("Запись существует.");
}  else {
 fputs($f,$write_text); 
 fclose($f);
   echo("Запись добавлена.");
}
```